# Calculating median of differences of columns

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I am tracking production of a lot of items. For each item I have timestamps along about 15 registration points in the production process. I want to create a Pivot with statistics of the time it takes items to go from point x to point y.

A simplified dataset:

[image: simplified dataset]

Say I want to analyze how much time it takes from packing to shipping. I'm trying to create a measure like this:

```
PackToShip:=CALCULATE(
  MEDIAN(
      Shipped-Packed
  );
  Shipped<>BLANK();
  Packed<>BLANK()
)
```

So far I only get error messages that "The MEDIAN function only accepts a column reference as the argument number 1."

I know I could create calculated columns for each combination of points, but for 15 points that's a lot of columns.
Can I do a measure "conditional (calculate) Median of a difference of two datetime columns" without creating a column for differences?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't create a column that calculates (shipped-packed), and run MEDIAN() on that. Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: I prefer not to create a column for each difference, because there's quite a number of columns. Creating a measure that does it all in one go seems more elegant, and requires less maintenance (once I got an example formula right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a measure:

```
PackToShip =
MEDIANX (
    FILTER (
        'Dataset',
        'Dataset'[Shipped] <> BLANK () &&
        'Dataset'[Packed]  <> BLANK ()
    ),
    DATEDIFF ( 'Dataset'[Packed], 'Dataset'[Shipped], MINUTE )
)
```

where 'Dataset' is the name of your table.

The formula first filters your dataset to avoid blanks, then iterates the resulting table record by record, calculating difference between start and end dates in minutes (you can change that to another interval). Finally, it computes the median of the calculated differences.